# Bootstrap - cutoff overflowing breadcrumbs with an ellipsis

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a list contained inside of a div. I want to constrain the list to be all on one line, and to cut off any text that overflows the div with an ellipsis.

How can I do this?

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="#bar">Browse</a></li>
    <li><a href="#foo">Chairs</a></li>
    <li class="active">Super Awesome Chair with mighttttty powers</li>
</ol>

.breadcrumb {
    width: 300px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/njfawg6e/1/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give the following CSS a try:

```
.breadcrumb {
    width: 300px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.breadcrumb li {
    display: inline;
}
```

Check out [this article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-overflow/) for additional information on `text-overflow`.

Comment: This truncates the whole breadcrumb, which is great if the over-long title is the last one. How would you truncate each path part in the breadcrumb, each with a maximum width?

Answer (score 4):

In Bootstrap 3 (and now also in 4!), I utilized the following code to achieve truncating specific elements in the breadcrumbs. Be warned that this does disable some flexbox functionality in Bootstrap 4 as we're now inlining the breadcrumbs.

```
.breadcrumb li {
  display: inline;         // force the inlining
  max-width: 200px;        // the actual width, you can make this bit responsive, increasing the width as your viewport increases. I suggest to utilize the native Bootstrap media-breakpoints (i.e. media-breakpoint-up(md)).
  white-space: nowrap;     // remove the wrapping and breaking of text in the breadcrumbs
  overflow: hidden;        // hide our overflow
  text-overflow: ellipsis; // return ellipsis for the overflow.
}
```

It would look something like this (in Bootstrap 4):

[image: It would look something like this]